# Is using Plugins a bad practice?

Tags: plugins, jquery-plugins, web, fullpage.js

I apologize if this is the wrong section, if so, I will delete and re-post somewhere else. 
But my question I had is, do other programmers, especially employers, look down for use of Plugins? I have never before used one, except today. I am creating a new Portfolio site for myself, and in order to deal with all the hassle of creating responsive full page websites, used FullPage.js. Now when I used this I couldn't help feel some guilt as if I was cheating.
What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338491/jquery-plugins-is-it-a-good-practice?rq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2773109/too-many-jquery-plugins?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Thank you for the link @Thilo !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically, a web developer wants to get a job done. It doesn't matter if they use plugins to help them along the way, as plugins just save you time. For example, if you are developing a portfolio page, you don't want to spend several months figuring out how to make a responsive page when a convenient plugin can help you do it. **Using plugins is time efficient and a common practice**, so don't feel guilty. You are being efficient and getting the job done.

Comment: "Typically a web developer wants to get a job done". That attitude is even more prevalent in employers, I think. They want the web developer to get the job done.

Comment: Definitely good to hear that this isn't immoral. I feel as if I should complete a website as fast as possible with still giving great quality. I also liked how @maiorano84 touched up on learning it yourself, but when its only a learning exercise. Thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

No. Quite the contrary, if a plugin fulfills your use-case and time is a resource that needs to spent wisely on a given project, then it can be considered a *good* practice to use it and focus on the application you're building. Additionally, thoroughly vetted plugins will typically also take care of security issues that you might not have considered during the process of rolling your own.

However, if you're still learning certain things and you feel that a plugin abstracts away too much of the underlying concepts you're interested in figuring out on your own, then it's still recommended to try building it yourself (but only as a learning exercise).

Most plugins are open source, so once you finally get a working prototype, compare your code to the plugin's. What problems did you solve? How did their code differ from yours?

Comment: Nice answer. More detailed than mine, yet has the same gist, with the concept of being time efficient, unless you want to learn a certain skill.